# Компонент изменяет неконтролируемый вход для управления

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть следующей компонент, который при работе приложения линкует ошибку. Вроде бы, все работает, как убрать ошибку и почему она появяляется?

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {createNewUser, deleteUser, changeInfo, userInfo} from "../components/redux/action"

//классовый компонент.
class SecondWindow extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    
    
    handleOptionChange = e => {
        this.setState(
            {
                selectedOption:e.target.value
            }
        )
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();    
        const newUser = {
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            FIO: "Имя",
            position:"Должность",
            birthDay: "год/месяц/день",
            sex: true,
            fired: false
        };        
        this.props.createNewUser(newUser); // создаем нового пользователя
        this.props.userInfo(newUser); // закватывает текущего юзера для работы в форме
        this.props.setActive(this.props.items.items.length); // добавляем выделение на нового пользователя
        
    }

    changeInputHandler = ({ target: t }) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          [t.name]: t.type === 'checkbox' || t.type === "radio"  ? t.checked : t.value,
          
        }));
        
        
        let newValue;
        if(t.type === "radio"){
            newValue = !this.props.items.activeUser.sex;
        }else{
            newValue = t.type === 'checkbox'  ? t.checked : t.value;
        }
                
        const valueForUpdate = {
            id: this.props.items.activeUser.id,
            box: t.name,
            newValue: newValue 
        };        
        this.props.changeInfo(valueForUpdate);
      }

    deleteUser = () => {        
        this.props.deleteUser(this.props.items.activeUser);        
    }
    

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div className="input-group mb-3">                    
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="ФИО"
                    name="FIO" 
                    onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                    value={this.props.items.activeUser.FIO}
                    maxLength="15"></input>
                </div>
                <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
                name ="position"
                onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                value={this.props.items.activeUser.position}                
                >                    
                    <option value = "Не назначено">Не назначено</option>
                    <option value="Старший разработчик">Старший разработчик</option>
                    <option value="Младший разработчик">Младший разработчик</option>
                    <option value="Эйчар">Эйчар</option>
                    <option value="Уборщик">Уборщик</option>
                </select>

                <div className="form-group ">                
                    <div className="mb-3"></div>
                        <input className="form-control" type="date"  id="example-date-input"
                        name ="birthDay"
                        onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                        value={this.props.items.activeUser.birthDay}></input>  
                </div>
              


               
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" 
                     id="flexRadioDefault1"
                     
                     name ="sex"
                     onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                     checked = {this.props.items.activeUser.sex}
                    ></input>
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault1">
                    М
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" 
                    id="flexRadioDefault1"
                    
                    name ="sex"
                    onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                    checked = {!this.props.items.activeUser.sex}
                    
                    ></input>
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault1">
                    Ж
                    </label>
                
                </div>
                
                
                
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  id="flexCheckDefault"
                    name ="fired"
                    onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                    checked={this.props.items.activeUser.fired}
                    
                    ></input>
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckDefault">
                    Уволен
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick = {this.submitHandler}                 
                 >Добавить нового сотрудника</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger"
                 onClick = {this.deleteUser}
                 disabled = {Object.keys(this.props.items.activeUser).length===0 ? true : false}
                 >Удалить выбранного сотрудника</button>  
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {    
    return {
        items: state.items,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    createNewUser: createNewUser,
    deleteUser:deleteUser,
    changeInfo:changeInfo,
    userInfo: userInfo
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SecondWindow);
```

ошибка

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
    at input
    at div
    at form
    at SecondWindow (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:522:5)
    at Connect(SecondWindow) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:33750:75)
    at div
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:55:76)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:33463:20)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:67
error @ react-dom.development.js:43
updateWrapper @ react-dom.development.js:1533
updateProperties @ react-dom.development.js:9376
commitUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:10252
commitWork @ react-dom.development.js:21401
commitMutationEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23401
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23121
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:646
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:646
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22420
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
```

Answer (score 1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Насколько я вижу по ошибке, то дело в том, что Вы не задали изначальное состояние для велью инпута. Ошибка кроется здесь:

```
value={this.props.items.activeUser.FIO}
```

Вы уверены, что items - это не массив, а объект?